# Is an adjective/noun adjunct carried by reference with the word "another"

Tags: adjectives, attributive-nouns

I am looking for the best interpretation of the phrase:

> ... if one structured property contains another, only one of them can be repeated.

Which is central to [a StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34790724).

In particular, of the following two interpretations, which is (arguably more) correct:

1. "if one structured property contains another **property**, ..."
2. "if one structured property contains another **structured property**, ..."

Alternatively, is the phrase impossible to disambiguate?

Are there any rules of linguistic canon that may apply?

Comment: Ask yourself whether 'One small brown toadstool is difficult to tell from another' is ambiguous.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Great illustration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It this case it is not impossible to disambiguate because the word "one" semantically draws the line for you:

> ... if **one** structured property contains **an**other, only **one** of them can
>   be repeated.

It's *"**one**"* unto *"**an**other."*  The word "one" pointedly precedes and so captures both the noun "property" and its adjunct "structured" and carries them both unto "*an*other," or "*one* other."  If the sentence didn't use a anything before "structure," neither an article nor "one," I might not be so firm in this conviction.  As it stands, though, the "***one***" clearly encompasses the adjunct "structured" and [parallels](http://www.chompchomp.com/rules/structurerules.htm) it into "***an*** other."